# asyncio.wait returning exception even when in `try ... except`

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-asyncio, discord.py

I have an `asyncio.wait` statement in my discord bot, so I can wait for multiple events at once. So that the bot doesn't get bogged down over time, I have a timeout for both of the wait statements. Even though the code is in a `try ... except` statement, it still raises errors.
Here's the part of the code causing the error:

```py
                try:

                    def check(reaction: discord.Reaction, user):
                        if user != bot.user and message.id == reaction.message.id:
                            return True

                    pending_tasks = [bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30, check=check),
                                     bot.wait_for('reaction_remove', timeout=30, check=check)]
                    done_tasks, pending_tasks = await asyncio.wait(pending_tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

                    reaction, user = await list(done_tasks)[0]

                    #reaction, user = await bot.wait_for(
                    #    "reaction_add", timeout=30, check=check
                    #)

                    user_check = user == ctx.author
                    emoji_check = any(
                        emoji == reaction.emoji for emoji in registered_emojis.keys()
                    )
                    if emoji_check and user_check:
                        next_page = self.paginator.get_page_reaction(reaction.emoji)
                        await message.edit(embed=self.paginator._pages[next_page])

                    #await message.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, user)

                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    bot_help = False
                    for emoji in registered_emojis.keys():
                        await message.remove_reaction(emoji, bot.user)
```

And here is the traceback:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-29' coro=<wait_for() done, defined at /Users/lucas/opt/anaconda3/envs/discord/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py:434> exception=TimeoutError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lucas/opt/anaconda3/envs/discord/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 490, in wait_for
    raise exceptions.TimeoutError()
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#id9) about `asyncio.wait`:

> Note that this function does not raise asyncio.TimeoutError. Futures or Tasks that aren’t done when the timeout occurs are simply returned in the second set.

On a personal note, `asyncio.wait` also does not propagate exceptions from tasks, including `asyncio.TimeoutError`.

Furthermore, since you use `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED` `asyncio.wait` returns when at least one of the tasks has completed. Other tasks might be still active and raise exception which never be retrieved.

And you extract result only first task:

`reaction, user = await list(done_tasks)[0]`

But `done_task` may contains more than one finished task despite `FIRST_COMPLETED` flag